# Filtering a column based on a value and copying the value from the corresponding value

Tags: vba, excel

This is a screenshot of my excel doc.
[image]

I want to apply filters based on values: Bimbo Mexico, Bimbo Canada and copy and paste the values(from column A & B) in a new sheet. I want to do this using macro as I am building a template for a client. Is there a way to do this? I know it can be done manually using filters manually but I want it to be based on a macro

I want the output like this:
[image: Desired Output]

I used recording macro and this is the macro I got,

```
Sub RecordedMacro()
'

' RecordedMacro Macro
'

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Sheets("report").Select
    Range("C1").Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$1001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Barcel"
    Columns("L:L").Select

    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("SkuRounds").Select

    Columns("S:S").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("report").Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$1001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "Bimbo Canada"
    Columns("L:L").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SkuRounds").Select
    Columns("T:T").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("report").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$1001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "Bimbo Latin Centro"
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SkuRounds").Select
    Columns("U:U").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("report").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$1001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "Bimbo México"
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SkuRounds").Select
    Columns("V:V").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I am copying data from sheet(report) to sheet(skurounds)

Comment: Turn on macro recording and then perform the operations manually to get the result you want and then stop recording.  Edit the created macro to suit your needs (usually removing all the .select/.activates and generalizing the filter to use variables or loops instead of the hardcoded values).

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanks for the help. After I finished recording the macro, I try to run the macro from the sheet where I pasted and it gives me error, however when I run it from the sheet I copy it works fine, the problem is I want to run it from the sheet where I paste it.

Comment: You'll need to declare your worksheets as variables and set them accordingly.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906880/setting-a-sheet-and-cell-as-variable) for an example on how to do so.

Comment: Also, for editing the macros, I am quite new to macros and it will take me a time editing the macros for loops. Is there any other way possible or this is the best way to go about it ?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you have so that we can see you've made original effort and then you'll probably get an answer

Comment: @tigeravatar see my update

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsReport As Worksheet
    Dim wsSKU As Worksheet
    Dim dictUnqCompanies As Object
    Dim aCompanies As Variant
    Dim vCompany As Variant
    Dim lDestCol As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsReport = wb.Sheets("report")
    Set wsSKU = wb.Sheets("skurounds")
    Set dictUnqCompanies = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lDestCol = wsSKU.Columns("S").Column

    'Clear previous results
    wsSKU.Range(wsSKU.Cells(1, "S"), wsSKU.Cells(1, wsSKU.Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Clear

    With wsReport.Range("C2", wsReport.Cells(wsReport.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            'Only 1 row of data
            wsSKU.Cells(1, lDestCol).Value = .Value
            .Parent.Cells(.Row, "L").Copy wsSKU.Cells(2, lDestCol)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            aCompanies = .Value
        End If
    End With

    For Each vCompany In aCompanies
        If Not dictUnqCompanies.exists(vCompany) Then
            dictUnqCompanies.Add vCompany, vCompany
            With wsReport.Range("C1", wsReport.Cells(wsReport.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
                .AutoFilter 1, vCompany
                wsSKU.Cells(1, lDestCol).Value = vCompany
                Intersect(.Parent.Columns("L"), .Offset(1).EntireRow).Copy wsSKU.Cells(2, lDestCol)
                lDestCol = lDestCol + 1
                .AutoFilter
            End With
        End If
    Next vCompany

End Sub
```